# What to do about "Operation failed: Update Indices DB Error: unknown error Debug" after upgrading to 4.7.25

Tags: error, 4.7, indices

This is related to a question I posted yesterday ([How does one delete "key indices"?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20725/how-does-one-delete-key-indices)), which was considered a duplicate of another question ([Performance Warning: Missing Indices. Mismatched Index Key](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20236/performance-warning-missing-indices-mismatched-index-key)). I am posting this new question because it seems to be a somewhat different issue and because adding a comment to one of those other posts didn't quite seem to fit with this.

It was suggested that installing 4.7.25 would resolve that issue. However, it seems to have produced a new one.

With 4.7.25 installed under Drupal 7, I now get this warning:

> Performance warning: Missing indices
>
> The following tables have missing indices. Click 'Update Indices'
>   button to create them.
>
> Table Name    Key Name    Expected Indices
>   civicrm_option_value  index_option_group_id_name  name(128),
>   option_group_id civicrm_case_contact  UI_case_contact_id  case_id,
>   contact_id

But when I click the Update Indices button, I get this error:

> Operation failed: Update Indices DB Error: unknown error Debug
>   information: DROP INDEX index_option_group_id_name ON
>   civicrm_option_value [nativecode=1553 ** Cannot drop index
>   'index_option_group_id_name': needed in a foreign key constraint]

Any help on what I can do about this would be appreciated. Please spell it out for me though; I'm not an expert at this stuff. Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Same problem for me on WP civicrm 4.7.25 installation.

Comment: I am still getting this after upgrade to 4.7.27. Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to work on your database directly. The following works for me - although the Status screen still shows the error until the Update Indices button is clicked again after the repair has been done (I presume it simply verifies the fix):

```
USE your_civicrm_db;
SHOW CREATE TABLE civicrm_case_contact;
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DROP INDEX `UI_case_contact_id` on civicrm_case_contact;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `UI_case_contact_id` ON civicrm_case_contact (case_id, contact_id);
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

If you do this via PhpMyAdmin (or similar), you can skip `USE your_civicrm_db;` since you'll have already navigated there.

Comment: Hi - on behalf of the OP - this is not working for us. We still encounter the "dop index ui_case_contact_id on civicrm_case_contact cannot drop index ui_case_contact_id needed in a foreign key constraint". This is after running the commands exactly as above including set foreign_key_checks=0;

Comment: Also, missing you at the sprint!

Comment: @JohnFF To state the obvious, it sounds like `foreign_key_checks` isn't being set to `0`. I've no idea why that should be the case for you. [OT: Hope the sprint is fun and that someone's brought a hacky sack; it's just the weather for it!]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Christian. When I run this I get the following error: **Error

SQL query:

DROP INDEX `UI_case_contact_id` on civicrm_case_contact

MySQL said: Documentation
#1553 - Cannot drop index 'UI_case_contact_id': needed in a foreign key constraint**

Comment: Could this have something to do with not having CiviCase enabled?

Comment: This type of error is still there in civicrm 4.7.29.